# How to select a specific element on a list of character based on its position

Tags: r, position, conditional-statements, character

I am a new R user and I need some help.

I have a dataframe that look like this :

```
Type                                     ID
pink-blue-blue-green-END                 125
blue-pink-END                            145
green-green-pink-END                     489
green-pink-blue-END                      478
pink-green-green-blue-END                546
```

And I want all the rows where "blue" is before "pink", the results would be

```
Type                                     ID
pink-blue-blue-green-END                 125
green-pink-blue-END                      478
pink-green-green-blue-END                546
```

And I would like to know another tips :) How I can do to delete all the "green" inside the list of character and having for example for the 1st row :

```
pink-blue-blue-END
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grep` to match the word "pink" followed by one or more characters followed by word "blue".  Note that `\\b` signify the word boundary

```
df1[grepl("\\bpink\\b-.*\\bblue\\b", df1$Type),]
#                       Type  ID
#1  pink-blue-blue-green-END 125
#4       green-pink-blue-END 478
#5 pink-green-green-blue-END 546
```

For the second case, use `gsub`

```
df1$Type <- gsub("green-", "", df1$Type)
```